# Charts Framework not loading (swift4)

Tags: ios, cocoapods, swift4

I am trying to load the cocoa pods charts. But its not working I am doing everything it says to in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P0TZpkISKa8&t=149s. But its not working this is a screenshot of a xcode project that is not loading.
[image]
Notice the Red text in the circle.

This project I download contains chart that is not in red text. 
[image]

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: @Koen import Charts is not being recognized.

Comment: Please share the actual error message.  Did you build the Charts target inside your project? Also, it looks like you have imported it twice in your project.

Comment: @Koen this is a video of me trying to install Charts https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iK6UINeFiDQ&feature=youtu.be.

Comment: Difficult to see, but it looks like you're typing `import charts` with a lowercase c. See also here: https://www.appcoda.com/ios-charts-api-tutorial/

Comment: @Koen this video is much better quality https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pYHmWtgWUpQ&feature=youtu.be.

Comment: @Koen I dont know how much that tutorial will help because its in swift 2.

Comment: It's about setting up your project with Charts. Don't think it is Swift version related. Worth a try.